# Can you help me about storage limits of firebase cloud storage?

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I am very confused about storage limits of cloud storage. I am new for firebase. Can you help me?
ı have a project about share documents. Users can upload projects and then others can see these documents. I use cloud storage. In graphics of usages, I understood that an app's tenure is only 5 gb area for upload(this is not for each day,totaly 5gb). ıf app exceeds this limit I pay extra money. Is this true?
ı think my app have potential of exceed this limit. Can you offer me some solutions.
Thanks...

Comment: I don't necessarily understand a problem in here. What would a solution look like?

Comment: First of all, I wanted to know if I understood the documents correctly. Is limit of app 5gb? (this include all users) .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question, not a programming question. Contact Firebase customer service to ask this sort of question. This site is for specific questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool (IDE, compiler, etc.). We don't offer support for off-site vendors or services.

Comment: The documented limit on the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) is per project, not per user. So you can store 5GB in total for free, no matter how many users you have. If you want to store more than 5GB, you'll have to upgrade up to the paid plan, at which point the first 5GB is free and you get charged for any additional usage.

Answer (score 1):

According to Firebase [prices](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) if you are a free user you will limited to 5GB per project and you can't exceed them and download capacity of 1 GB/day - 50K operation/day.
However, if you want more storage move to **Blaze plan** and you will pay $0.026/GB after first 5GB and ***Pay as you go***.

Comment: so if i have the total data 10gb that's mean i need to pay $0.13 for every month or only 1 time payment for the additional 5gb?

Comment: If you still have the 10GB stored, you'll pay again.